# Does .class files have an associated classpath?

Tags: java, classpath

Is the information on the classpath embedded into the class file?

I have a jar file that has a class I'm trying to compile a java program with, but it can never find the class that's inside the jar.

I've tried to compile with -cp path_to_the_jar, but it didn't work.

Comment: You're trying to run a JAR, or to compile a `.java` file using dependencies from that JAR? It's not clear in your question...

Comment: Can you provide the jar and the code you are trying to run?

Comment: Compile a .java using dependencies from the jar. Adding the jar to the Ambient Variables work, but it shouldn't be the solution for something that I'm using on just one program...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include jar itself on the classpath (not just the dir where the jar is):

javac -cp your_jar.jar YourJavaFile.java